# How can I link a callRecord to an outlook event?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft365

In our app we have a screen where we show the events from our user's Outlook calendar and the teams calls made by our user (that linked his O365 account and gave us the necessary permissions). We intercept these calls with a subscription on the callRecords (/communications/callRecords). All data comes from the Microsoft Graph API.

The thing is that when our users do a Teams meeting we get an event and a callRecord. When that happens we would like to detect the link between the two to show our user that those were related. Since the event is a Teams meeting and that the call starts with the "Join" button of the meeting in teams there should be a link somewhere, no?

The issue is that I can't find the link anywhere. Is there a way to detect the link between those two? An Id somewhere?

Thanks you!

**Update 2022:**
So, we used the WebJoinURL that @dani-mazahreh suggested, but be careful, some recurring events have the same WebJoinURL. So if it's a daily recurring event, you should add the day to the comparison.

Comment: You will receive the Id in the response by using [Create Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-an-event-in-a-specific-calendar) and you can use that Id to get items in the outlook calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i managed to do this is using the join URL. When creating an event, Microsoft Graph will return the join URL among other properties, save it and match with the join URL of the Call Record.

Comment: Thank you! It matches perfectly. I probably overlooked it by expecting the URL to simply contain the ID.

Comment: @JFlex
No problem! happened to me as well, i spent hours parsing the join URL trying to get out an Id from it then it hit me they are one and the same. It's a shame Microsoft does not provide direct matching Ids.